# Python Flask, is it possible to get string from a function in views.py to a <td> tag in html?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to figure out if I can get a value from a function in my views.py in an html page.

I know I can pass values for url with the url_for, but in this case I only want a value

html:

```
<tbody>
              {% for item in cart.items%}
              <tr onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for('views.item_detail', itemID=item) }}';">                      
                <td>
                  <img src="{{ url_for('views.display_item_image', itemID=item.id ) }}" class="rounded-circle" width="100" height="100" object-fit="cover" alt="product img">
                </td>
                <td>{{ item.item_name }}</td>
                **<td>{{ url_for('views.exampleFunction', itemID=item.id ) }}</td>**
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

So, all the url_for are working but the one in bold I wanted just for this example to display in the  tag the string I am returning in the views function bellow:

views.py

```
@views.route('/exampleFunction/<itemID>')
def exampleFunction(itemID):
    return 'test correct'+str(itemID)
```

Is this even possible? as it is the url_for is displaying "/exampleFunction/1" and that wasn't my objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, for an item with ID "232", you want the line

```html
<td>{{ url_for('views.exampleFunction', itemID=item.id ) }}</td>
```

to render in the html as

```html
<td>test correct232</td>
```

There are few ways to accomplish this goal.

### Template Global

If you want to define the function once and have it available on all of your templates automatically, you can use [template_global](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.template_global). From [the Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/):

> **template_global(name=None)**
>
> A decorator that is used to register a custom template global function. You can specify a name for the global function, otherwise the function name will be used. Example:
>
> ```py
> @app.template_global()
> def double(n):
>    return 2 * n
> ```

Register the template_global in `__init__.py`:

```py
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    …

    @app.template_global('exampleFunction')
    def exampleFunction(itemID):
        return 'test correct' + str(itemID)
    

    …

    return app
```

Then you can just call the function in your template like a variable:

```
<tbody>
  {% for item in cart.items%}
    <tr onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for('views.item_detail', itemID=item) }}';">                      
      <td>
        <img src="{{ url_for('views.display_item_image', itemID=item.id ) }}" class="rounded-circle" width="100" height="100" object-fit="cover" alt="product img">
      </td>
      <td>{{ item.item_name }}</td>
      **<td>{{ exampleFunction(item.id) }}</td>**
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

### Inline & Imported Functions

Functions can be passed to templates like any other variable.

#### Define Elsewhere and Import

If you want to define your function in a separate file from your route definition, it can be imported and then passed to the template.

#### Define Inline

A function defined in the same file as the route definition is available to pass to the template.

abc.py

```py
def foo(input):
    stringFOO = f"The input to the foo funtion was: {input}"
    return stringFOO
```

blueprint_routes.py

```py
from abc import foo

def bar(input):
    stringBAR = f"The input to the bar function was: {input}"
    return stringBAR

@blueprint.route('/example')
def example():
    return render_template(
        '/blueprint/example.html',
        foo=foo,
        bar=bar
        )
```

Once passed to the template, the function can be called just as with the `template_global` function.

example.html

```html
  <div class="centered">
    In this paragraph, we use the foo function, which was imported to blueprint_routes.py. <br />
    {{ foo('Foo Input') }}
  </div>
  <div class="centered">
    In this paragraph, we use the bar function, which was defined in blueprint_routes.py. <br />
    {{ bar('Bar Input') }}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it and indeed it works perfectly.

However I have a question now. Is there any possibility of doing the same thing in other other py files? For example can I have a function on a file called abc.py that I could access in the same way?

Comment: They can be accessed in a *similar* way. `template_global` functions are available on all templates by default, but other functions can be passed to a template as arguments to the `render_template()` function.

I have expanded my answer to elaborate.